# Wrapping Expanded Widget in Padding Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

While learning flutter, I was trying to add some padding to an `Image` widget which was wrapped inside an `Expanded` widget, my approach was to wrap the `Expanded` widget with a `Padding` widget, but as a result the image actually overflowed.
When I changed the code to wrapping the `Image` widget inside a `Padding` instead, it worked fine. So my question here is, why did the image overflow when I used the `Padding` on the `Expanded` widget instead of the image ? Is it not possible to do that in Flutter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure your issue was not overflowing of the `Expanded` widget when you wrapped it with `Padding`, but rather Flutter threw an `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget` exception. That is because widgets like `Expanded` and `Flexible` has to be direct children of `Column`, `Row` or `Flex` widgets. That is why the only solution is to use the `Padding` over the child of `Expanded`.

Summarising, this code will not work:

```
Row(
      children: const [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Expanded(
            child: Icon(Icons.icecream_outlined),
          ),
        ),
        Text("SomeTextyTextHere"),
      ],
    ),
```

it will not work because `Expanded` has to be a direct child of `Row`.

This code however will work fine:

```
Row(
      children: const [
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.icecream_outlined),
          ),
        ),
        Text("SomeTextyTextHere"),
      ],
    ),
```